# I can access my Pi through the network on one PC but not on the other

Tags: networking, windows, samba

I have a Pi set up and connected to my router through Ethernet. I have two Windows 10 machines - a laptop and a desktop - which I need to access the Pi with. I am using Samba in order to connect to the Windows machines.

The Pi and the machines are all in the same workgroup. I can see my desktop and the Pi from my laptop, but on the desktop I can only see the laptop. Furthermore, from other tests I have figured out that the desktop does not even know the Pi exists on the network. The desktop is connected through Ethernet and the laptop through WiFi.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you ping the IP address of the Pi from the Desktop?  If you can then you are experiencing some sort of name resolution problem.  Are you using DNS for name resolution?

Comment: No, I cannot ping the Pi from the desktop, and vice versa. However, I can ping both from the laptop, again vice versa.

Comment: What are the ip addresses and subnet mask of each device?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Desktop: IP: 192.168.1.101 Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Pi: IP: 192.168.1.100 Subnet: 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, DD-WRT on my router was not configured to allow connections between Ethernet ports.